# Hibernate criteria for contains/in in text array in postgresql

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, hibernate

I have an entity named box..Each box contains some parameters which can be same for many unique ids. Unique ids are only number and don't have any other role.
SO I created them as a text array in postgresql and in Java I made them as ArrayList and mapped them with Custom User Type.
        package com.geniedoc.utils;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class PostgresTextArrayType implements UserType {

    protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = {Types.ARRAY};
     public Class<String> returnedClass() {
            return String.class;
        }

     public final int[] sqlTypes() {
            return SQL_TYPES;
        }


        @Override
        public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names,
                SessionImplementor arg2, Object arg3)
                throws HibernateException, SQLException {
             List<String> list = null;
            String nameVal = resultSet.getString(names[0]);
             if (nameVal != null) {
                 nameVal = nameVal.substring(1,nameVal.length()-1);
                 list = new ArrayList<>();
                 StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(nameVal, ",");
                 while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                     String val = (String) tokenizer.nextElement();
                     list.add(val);
                 }
             }

             return list;

        }

        @Override
        public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index,
                SessionImplementor arg3) throws HibernateException,
                SQLException {
             Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
                if (value == null) {
                    statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("statement>>>>"+statement);
                    System.out.println("value>>>>"+ value);
                    System.out.println("index>>>>"+index);
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    ArrayList<String> parameter=new ArrayList<>();
                    if(value instanceof Array)
                    {   parameter=(ArrayList<String>) value;
                    }else
                    { 
                        parameter.add((String) value);
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> list=parameter;
                    String[] castObject = Arrays.copyOf(list.toArray(), list.toArray().length, String[].class);
                    Array array = connection.createArrayOf("text", castObject);
                    statement.setArray(index, array);
                    System.out.println("statement>>>>"+statement);
                }
        }
        @Override
        public final Object deepCopy(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean isMutable() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public final Object assemble(final Serializable serializable, final Object arg1)
                throws HibernateException {
             return serializable;
        }

        @Override
        public final Serializable disassemble(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
            return (Serializable) o;
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException {
            if (x == y) {
                return true;
            } else if (x == null || y == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return x.equals(y);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public final int hashCode(final Object x) throws HibernateException {
            return x.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public final Object replace(
            final Object original,
            final Object target,
            final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
            return original;
        }
          private String serialize(List<String> list) {
                StringBuilder strbul = new StringBuilder();
                Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
                strbul.append("{");
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    strbul.append(iter.next());
                    if (iter.hasNext()) {
                        strbul.append(",");
                    }
                }
                strbul.append("}");
                return strbul.toString();
            }


}
```

This is my hibernate criteria :-

```
    Session session=getSession();
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Box.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("unique_id", unique_id));
    return (Unit)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

I need to get the Box which contains a particular unique id.But it doesn't work.
It returns result only if I have one value in text array in DB.
But If i Have multiple values in DB, it doesn't show any result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `UserType` is usually not worth the effort. You'll be better off adding `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` and `@PostLoad` functions to your class, since Postgres accepts a string format for arrays. Since it's just numbers, the transformation is pretty straight forward.

```
@Transient
private long[] theids;

@Column(name = "the_ids")
private String therealids;

@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
private void encode() {
    therealids = "{" + java.util.Arrays.toString(theids) + "}";
}

@PostLoad
private void decode() {
    String[] ids = therealids.split(",");
    theids = new long[ids.length];
    if (ids.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    int last = ids.length - 1;
    // remove the "{"
    ids[0] = ids[0].substr(1);
    // remove the "}"
    ids[last] = ids[last].substr(0, ids[last].length() - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) theids[i] = Long.parseLong(ids[i]);
}
```

There are at least 4 optimizations you can do to this code to make it faster and less memory-hungry, but this is the short version.

If you want to do the same, but with string arrays, there you have to be very aware of the proper escape syntax for arrays in that scenario, and worse, the optional double-quotes.